# What does the counter on the Vernal Fountain mean?

Tags: dragonvale

In the buy menu for "Decorations" it lists a counter that shows 0/25.  What does this counter mean? Does it have any game benefit or impact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counter goes up when you purchase one, just like Buildings, so it's a limit on how many you can purchase. From the wiki article on the [Vernal Fountain](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Vernal_Fountain) it sounds like the game lags if you have too many of these items (they're animated) so they limit you to prevent you from crashing the game.

I own one of these and I can confirm it doesn't give a boost to Bloom dragons at all and appears perfectly decorative. None of the other decorations have in-game benefits either (other than raising the meaningless Visitors counter) so this seems normal.